# Regex Expression & string In C# Question

Tags: c#, regex, string-concatenation

I want to split my string `s1 = 6/28/2010 4:46:36 PM`  and `s2 = 16:46:36.5013946` . 
and concatenate them to new `s3 = 20010062816463650`. But when I split s2. my regex doesn't work. I was paused now.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConAppTest
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s1 = ""; // date
            string s2 = ""; // time
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", DateTime.Now);
            s1 = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
            s2 = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();

            Regex regex1 = new Regex(@" |:|/");    //6/28/2010 2:19:21 PM
            char[] separators1 = { ' ', '/' };
            foreach (string sub1 in regex1.Split(s1))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Word1: {0}", sub1);
            }

            Regex regex2 = new Regex(@":|.");  //14:19:21.8771215
            char[] separators2 = { ':', '.' };
            foreach (string sub2 in regex2.Split(s2))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Word2: {0}", sub2);
            }
        }



    }
}
//output
//6/28/2010 4:46:36 PM
//16:46:36.5013946
//Word1: 6
//Word1: 28
//Word1: 2010
//Word1: 4
//Word1: 46
//Word1: 36
//Word1: PM
//Word2:
//Word2:
//Word2:
//Word2:
//Word2:
//Word2:
//Word2:
//Word2:
//Word2:
//Word2:
//Word2:
//Word2:
//Word2:
//Word2:
//Word2:
//Word2:
//Word2:
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you using `RegEx` at all for this?

Use [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) or [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) to parse the input string to a `DateTime` object (if you need an *exact* parse, there are also `ParseExact` and `TryParseExact` that take a format string).

You can then use `DateTime.ToString` with a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) that will output the exact output you want directly from `DateTime` objects.

```
DateTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssff");
```

Answer (score 3):

A dot (`.`) matches *any* character when used in a regular expression. You need to escape it with a backslash:

```
Regex regex2 = new Regex(@":|\.");
```

Note that this is entirely separate from the escaping performed in string literals - it's part of the regular expressions language, not the C# language.

(I would also agree with Oded's suggestion that using a regular expression probably isn't the most appropriate solution here anyway.)